# Aligning a system of equations in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, equation-editor

I'm working on a Word document rich of formulas that needs to be collected into a curly bracket.

This is  what I managed to do up to now:
[image]

The problem is that I'd like all the equations to be left aligned to the bracket. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Possible dupe: [Auto align left equations in Office Word 2013?](//superuser.com/q/873769)

Comment: @DavidPostill nope, that command is to align the entire group. I'm referring to the alignment of each line here.

Comment: You can't remove the group, left align, and then add the group again?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this with LaTeX in Word 365 using a combination of `\eqarray` and `&` characters before the `=` for each line (or wherever else you want the alignment to be).

For example:

```
\left{ \eqarray{\bm{\nu} &= \bm{B^{-\top}} \left(\bm{B^{-1}}\bm{a_{s}}\right)@ &= \bm{B^{-\top}}\bm{y}}\right.
```

produces the result:

[image: Word display image]

If you put the `&` at the beginning of each line it will align everything next to the curly bracket.
For example:

```
\left{ \eqarray{&\bm{\nu} = \bm{B^{-\top}} \left(\bm{B^{-1}}\bm{a_{s}}\right)@ &= \bm{B^{-\top}}\bm{y}}\right.
```

gives:

[image: Word display image 2]